# Get Multiple Lines in XML with JDOM

Tags: xml, jdom

I have a code Snippet that prints out a part of an XML document:

```
<SPEECH>
<SPEAKER>KENT</SPEAKER>
<LINE>I thought the king had more affected the Duke of</LINE>
<LINE>Albany than Cornwall.</LINE>
</SPEECH>
```

code snippet:

```
List<Element> speech = scene.getChildren("SPEECH");
for(int a = 0; a < speech.size(); a++)
    {
        Element speak = speech.get(a);
        System.out.println(speak.getChildren());
        System.out.println("SPEAKER : " + speak.getChildText("SPEAKER"));
        System.out.println("LINE : " + speak.getChildText("LINE")); 
    }
```

The problem is it only prints out the first line in XML. Can someone suggest a way to count and print multiple LINES in the XML file (NOTE, there are more than two lines in some parts of the XML)?

Here are the libraries I have imported so far in my code:

```
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need use the enhanced-for loops. Consider this:

```
for(Element speech : scene.getChildren("SPEECH")) {
    for (Element part : speech.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(part.getName() + " : " + part.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your snippet, the IDE complains about casting from Element to Object. This most likely is in the right direction, but is there any way to tweak it so that the variable scene is referenced correctly as an Element?

Comment: I had one mis-named variable in my code above, which I have now fixed, but, assuming your code before actually ran, there's no reason why my suggestion won't run. Your code woul dhave the same `scene` Object problem that mine would. Are you sure you are using JDOM throughout?

Comment: I will list all the libraries I imported. I am still learning how to use JDOM so I am only assuming I am or atleast a class from JDOMs jar file..

Comment: OK, if you are new to JDOM, and you have no legacy requirements, why are you using JDOM 1.x instead of 2.x? See http://jdom.org/ and get the latest 2.0.6 download, or update your maven dependency to org.jdom artifact jdom2: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jdom%7Cjdom2%7C2.0.6%7Cjar

Comment: The project requirement asked to use the JAR file which is JDOM 1.x specifically (not sure why).

Comment: by the way, I had no idea you actually upkeep the JDOM library.. That's pretty cool :)

Comment: JDOM versions 1.x are designed to support Java back to version 2. In Java 5, Generics were introduced. About 5 years ago JDOM 2.x was introduced with full support for generics, etc. The code you are using is about 10 years old, and is not maintained. Please upgrade.